# Shell Startup vs. Common Startup?

Tags: shell, startup

Just a quick curious question -

What is the difference between these two commands? It looks like they point to different folders when I run them. I see guides that use each of them-

1. Shell:common startup
2. Shell:startup

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If I remember correctly,

`shell:startup` (the currently logged in user.)

`shell:common startup` (global, all users on the system.)